# await returning undefined when i call async function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

So in main.ts i am trying to call class method `processResponse` to get the data back from handler but it always return `custObject` undefined its nor even stepping into `processResponse` function , what is implemented wrong in below code ?

main.ts

```
private async custResponse(data: any): Promise < any > {
    const custObject = await RequestResponseHandler.processResponse(data);
    return custObject;
}
```

handler.ts

```
public static async processResponse(data: any): Promise<any> {
    let response: any = {};
    console.log("Data>>..>>>>", data); // undefined
    try {
        if (data.Header.StatusCode === "0000") {
            response = data.Details;
            const tokenId = await this.cacheResponse(response);
            response.Header.tokenID = tokenId;
            return response;
        }
    } catch (err) {
            return data;
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you arrive at this assumption, i.e. how are you testing/verifying your code?

Comment: Note in your try block you don't return anything if your if statement fails

Comment: i have debug mode on its assinging undefined to custObject

Comment: If you log `data` what is the result?

Comment: My guess is the typo: `data.Header.StatusCode === "2200"` should be `data.Header.StatusCode === "200"`. This is causing your `response` not to return, thus causing undefined.

Comment: @FrankerZ No 2200 is success code from our backend

Comment: I would recommend that you not use `any` as often as you are; this may help you solve your issue.

Comment: And you're sure that's returning a string? `console.log(data.Header.StatusCode)`

Comment: @MaxBaldwin as i said its not calling processResponse at all

Comment: Is `data.Header.StatusCode` definitely a string, or could something be converting it to a number, causing the `===` comparison to evaluate to false?

Comment: yes it is a string

Comment: @MaxBaldwin i see data values where it passed as arg but when i print its logging undefined not sure

Comment: Can you add the code that is doing the logging where you are actually doing it. Any chance you're not waiting for the response to complete before printing?

Comment: added to question

Comment: How are you calling custResponse ? Are you passing arguments in to it?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `console.log("Data>>..>>>>", data);` is `undefined` that means the issue is somewhere upstream. You are not passing anything in the data argument to this method. Try checking where you are calling `custResponse` method and see if the data is actually being passed or not (Its probably not).

As for the undefined return, In your code you are not returning anything if the status code is not OK (In the try block). Try putting some return at the end.

```
public static async processResponse(data: any): Promise<any> {
    //....
    //try catch stuff...
    //....
    return data //or something else

}
```

Comment: Thanks man, solved a similar issue returning a new Promise inside a try/catch block!